# Google Play Maps, Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My google maps are not setting up on my android studio! I have check many solutions here and have followed each of them but still have no luck.

It's mainly from the googleplay services and repository dependencies that is causing the problem. I tried many solutions but it didn't work.
I will post the error logs.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            demomap:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            demomap:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0
>   Could not find com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/P:/Software/Android SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/22.2.0/mediarouter-v7-22.2.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            demomap:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.8.0

Build-Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sonyvaio.demomap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Was one of the solutions you tried looking for this library? com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.

Comment: You need to have downloaded Google API android support library an Google repositories via SDK Manager

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: well i have it installed! but if you closely look, the error path is inside the google repository and i have both google play services and repositories installed and updated!

Comment: @pengrad posted my build.gradle

Comment: Have you Rebuild/Clear the project?

Comment: So, did you check my answer?

Comment: @SwarnanilKundu come on, close the question

Answer (score 2):

Your build.gradle is correct.
Just install this two Extras from Android SDK Manager

[image: android sdk manager]